# "NoReverseMatch" error in django-photolog

Tags: python, django

I try to run the https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue image galery example_project (https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue/tree/master/example_project).

Admin page work properly.

[image]

Main page show the error

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'photologue-gallery-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Django 1.6

Python 3.3

Could someone help?

[image]

Comment: have you synced the database. It may also be a coding error where a query list is not checked for empty values. Need code extracts from where the error occurred to help.

Comment: db - synced. Code line here - https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue/blob/master/example_project/example_project/templates/base.html#L40. It's an official example from photolog author, I didn't change anything

Comment: I suspect that you have not included the photologue urls in your urls.py. [Check here for details.](https://django-photologue.readthedocs.org/en/2.8/pages/installation.html#add-the-urls)

Comment: Url added - look https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue/blob/master/example_project/example_project/urls.py#L11